# DropDownList Showing First Item Empty

Tags: c#, .net

[image]

Every time this `Dropdown` is showing first Item *Blank*

```
 ComboBox cb;
 List<string> namesCollection=new List<string>();
 namesCollection.Add("---- Select ----");
 namesCollection.Add("ABC1");
 namesCollection.Add("ABC2");
 namesCollection.Add("ABC3");
 namesCollection.Add("ABC4");
 foreach(string pname in namesCollection)
 cb.Items.Add(pname);
```

Does anyone have solution for this ?

Comment: Please, do not include IDE tag (Visual Studio) among tags if your question is not directly about it and you just write code in it. Problems with code are seldom connected to a code editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be defining the ComboBox right there in your code, so I'll assume it's actually displayed somewhere in your form / window.

It's normal for the ComboBox to display a blank line initially.

Specify the item you want to display, immediately after populating the ComboBox with data:

```
cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a line feed in your items collection. Hard to see. Adding a `cb.Items.Clear()` before populating is probably a good idea anyway and will get rid of the problem, if you can't locate it.